# Retrieving album artist info from third party API

Tags: javascript, html, angular.js

I've recently just started with AngularJS and the best way for me to learn is to get some criticism to find out how I can do things better. I did a small project that calls a third party API and shows a bit of the return data.

**HTML**

```
  <body ng-controller="Album">
    <div class="container">
      <input id="artist" type="text" placeholder="Enter artist name" ng-model="artist">
      <button ng-click="getAlbums()">Get Albums</button><br/><br/>
      <div id="albums" ng-repeat="album in albums">
        <div ng-if="albums.length > 0">
        <h2>Album Info</h2>
            {{album.name}}<br/>
            <img src="{{album.image}}">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

**Controller**

```
jamendoApp.controller('Album', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.getAlbums = function() {
    $http.get("http://api.jamendo.com/v3.0/albums/?client_id=b6747d04&format=jsonpretty&artist_name=" + $scope.artist)
         .success(function(data) {
            if(data.headers.status == 'success') {
              $scope.albums = data.results;
            }
            else {
              alert("Error - " + data.headers.error_message);
            }
         })
         .error(function(x, status, error) {
           alert(error);
         });
     };
});
```

What I'm specifically interested in knowing is:

- Am I writing the JavaScript for the controller correctly? It seems to work, but I can't help but feel like I'm not writing it the way actual JavaScript developers would.
- Am I using the AngularJS directives correctly in the HTML? I'm especially concerned if I'm using the ng-if as it's intended.
- Plus anything that may catch your eye that could be improved.

To view the whole application feel free to view it on [GitHub](https://github.com/jwood803/JamendoAngular).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some pointers:

- Move `$http.get` out of the controller to a [service](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.creating_services). Stuff that is not presentation logic should not be in your controller.
- `getAlbums` should probably be a method of the controller and not the `$scope` , see [this video on egghead.io](http://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-experimental-controller-as-syntax) on how to use controller as syntax.
- I don't really see the point in your `ng-if="albums.length > 0"`. Why is it there?
- It's common practice to postfix your controllers - so `AlbumController` or `AlbumCtrl` are more common names. I usually try to stick to conventions like this to convey intent more clearly.
- If you're considering minification - consider using the minification syntax - start by [reading this](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05).

Comment: Thanks for tips, Ben! I should have mentioned that I was in the process of moving the $http.get to a service. Would you also use a factory for that? For the ng-if directive, I was just more or less playing with that, but I thought it would have been best to not have the "Album Info" display before hitting the button.

Comment: Your `ng-repeat` should handle that, before there are any albums you should only see a comment in your HTML where the repeated parent `div` would go.